# how to hide wxpython status bar by default

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, wxpython

I am learning wxpython following the tutorials on [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/) about menu bars and status bars. Please forgive me if the question is stupid.

The code below from the website works fine, but I am curious how to hide the status bar by default (when the application window popup).

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)             
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):    

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        viewMenu = wx.Menu()

        self.shst = viewMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Show statubar', 
            'Show Statusbar', kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        self.shtl = viewMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Show toolbar', 
            'Show Toolbar', kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)

        viewMenu.Check(self.shst.GetId(), True)
        viewMenu.Check(self.shtl.GetId(), True)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ToggleStatusBar, self.shst)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ToggleToolBar, self.shtl)

        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        menubar.Append(viewMenu, '&View')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        self.toolbar.AddLabelTool(1, '', wx.Bitmap('texit.png'))
        self.toolbar.Realize()

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Ready')

        self.SetSize((350, 250))
        self.SetTitle('Check menu item')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)


    def ToggleStatusBar(self, e):        
        if self.shst.IsChecked():
            self.statusbar.Show()
        else:
            self.statusbar.Hide()

    def ToggleToolBar(self, e):        
        if self.shtl.IsChecked():
            self.toolbar.Show()
        else:
            self.toolbar.Hide()        

def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried to change one line above into:

```
viewMenu.Check(self.shst.GetId(), False)
```

Sadly, that didn't work out.

Willing to hear any advice! Thanks in advance!

Specs: wxpython: 2.8.12.1; python 2.7; Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, because `viewMenu.Check(..)` is called before UI initialization is done (before event loop begin), it may not fire event.

How about manually call `ToggleStatusBar` method after `viewMenu.Check`?

```
def InitUI(self):    
    ....
    viewMenu.Check(self.shst.GetId(), False)
    self.ToggleStatusBar(None)
```

Comment: This works well! Thanks! Just curious if any built-in functions can do that kind of "update" job?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you mean by Just curious if any built-in functions can do that kind of "update" job?
There is a wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI event, i've modifed your code to use it.

[UpdateUIEvent](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/UpdateUIEvent.html?highlight=updateuievent#UpdateUIEvent)

```
import wx


class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        viewMenu = wx.Menu()

        self.shst = viewMenu.Append(-1, 'Show statubar', 'Show Statusbar',
            kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        self.shtl = viewMenu.Append(-1, 'Show toolbar', 'Show Toolbar',
            kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)

        self.shst.Check(False)
        self.shtl.Check(True)

        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        menubar.Append(viewMenu, '&View')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        self.toolbar.AddLabelTool(1, '', wx.EmptyBitmap(16, 16))
        self.toolbar.Realize()

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Ready')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, self.on_update_status_bar, self.statusbar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, self.on_update_tool_bar, self.toolbar)

        self.SetSize((350, 250))
        self.SetTitle('Check menu item')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def on_update_status_bar(self, event):
        event.Show(self.shst.IsChecked())

    def on_update_tool_bar(self, event):
        event.Show(self.shtl.IsChecked())


def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I like this feature. Yet one problem running on my machine is that the later checking and unchecking status bar menuitem don't seem to fire the event. Might be a problem of my machine if the code runs well on yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way would be better.

```python
statusBarHandle.Hide()
self.SetStatusBar(None) #Disable Status Bar
#Enable
statusBarHandle.Show()
self.SetStatusBar(statusBarHandle) #Back created StatusBar(self.CreateStatusBar function)
#Useful tip: for update all widgets in AUI, use AUI function Update()
#For sizers you need to use the Layout() or Update() function
```